# Autobahn twisted websocket server does not send messages to client unless it receives a message from a client

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I'm running an autobahn/twisted python websocket server and I'm having a problem with sending messages to clients.  It seems to only sends messages to clients when a client sends it a message.  For some reason, If I want to force out messages to connected clients, the message gets stuck in a queue until any client sends me a message.  At that point, all the queued messages go out to all clients.

I was able to reproduce this behavior with both python clients and javascript clients against this python autobahn/twisted websocket server.

Can anyone tell me how to properly send a message from the websocket server to all connected clients?  My goal is to let clients subscribe to events, then the server just sends them event messages.  But for some reason this above behavior isn't letting the server send clients messages unless they first send the server a message.

**You can easily reproduce this using the code below:**  You only need one server and one client to reproduce it.  I used two different clients to prove that the issue was with the server.

[Autobahn/twisted python websocket server](https://gist.github.com/lampshade9909/2aff0460d0ba3345a699cc76f3e97e1a)

[Javascript websocket client](https://gist.github.com/lampshade9909/5ca2d5302eff0c3323bea74eab83fd16)

[Python websocket client](https://gist.github.com/lampshade9909/d1aa47adc219d072431b6e4e55db130a)

Regardless of which websocket client I'm using, I'm seeing the same behavior.  So clearly the websocket server is queueing messages for some reason.

[image]

Server logs, every 5 seconds on the dot it claims to be sending a message.

[image]

Python client shows the difference in time between when the server sent the message and when the python client received it.  Notice they come in chunks and some have a massive delay.

[image]

Javascript client gets them in chunks of 4 only after it sends the server a new message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted APIs are not threadsafe.  With the exception of `reactor.callFromThread`, you may only call them in the thread the reactor is running in.

Try not using multithreading at all in your Twisted-based program, as a start.  I don't see anything in your code that calls for multiple threads.

Comment: How do you send a message to all clients (or a subset of clients) from the main thread?  Isn't the main thread essentially stuck on the line `reactor.run()` ?

Comment: I was able to get it working using `reactor.callFromThread()`.  That makes sense.  But i'm not sure I see a good solution not using multithreading at all.  Because I need some sort of service or thread or process that detects when new data has arrived so it knows when to send the new data to the clients.  I suppose I could make that a separate process that connects as a websocket client, then I could tell the server (via this new client) that there's new data available.  That way the server only interacts with it via websocket protocol on the main thread.  That seems like a bad solution though

Comment: If you could say that there is an overarching goal to Twisted it is "detect when new data has arrived without using multithreading or multiprocessing".  It sounds like you may not have internalized the execution model of Twisted-based programs.  https://twistedmatrix.com/~exarkun/pycon-presentation.html might help.

Comment: That may very well be the case.  I was simply looking for a good quality websocket server when I found Twisted.  I'll take a look at this.  Thanks